# Splunk two SourceTypes same columns into multiline chart with 2 axis

Tags: splunk

SourceType=A | table EventTime NumOutages
SourceType=B | table EventTime NumOutages

table EventTime NumOutages_A NumOutages_B

X axis will be time by hour and Y axis will be the NumOutages one line per sourcetype

I tried join and a few other examples but for some reason it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample SPL is not valid.  Since the two sourcetypes have the same fields, you don't need `join`.  Feel free to change `avg` to the function that best presents your data (max, min, etc.).

```
sourcetype=A OR sourcetype=B | timechart span=1h avg(NumOutages) by sourcetype
```

Comment: Thanks, ya was generalizing it a bit. This worked, I was real close a few hours ago. lol thanks